# Different data for www and no-www in Google Webmasters Tools

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect, backlinks, no-www

My Webmasters Tools home page contains `example.com` and `www.example.com` in the sites section.

There is a rewrite rule (301 redirect) on my server that redirects all requests from `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

Now I am worried why dashboard pages for `example.com` and `www.example.com` show different data? These pages show different keywords and different amount of links to my site.

Is it normal? Is there any way to "merge" collected data? Or maybe there is a way to make Google treat `example.com` and `www.example.com` as one site (as it really is)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Site Configuration > Settings, there is an option for preferred domain. Select the one you want and allow Google some time to transfer all your data to the preferred profile.

Comment: thank you for the answer. what data should be displayed in non-preferred profile after transferral is complete?

Comment: After my changes took affect, all categories showed No data available.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the preferred domain in your Webmaster Account? It can be found under settings.